# Stacking monitorenter and monitorexit in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

Is it true that monitorenter and monitorexit bytecodes do not stack like in the following code?

```
monitorenter;
//code1
    monitorenter;
    //code2
    monitorexit;
//code3
monitorexit;
```

Is it true that code 3 will not execute? How is it remedied?

**Edit:**
With "do not stack" I meant: If a monitor is entered while already inside a monitor, will it cause some trouble?

Comment: Sorry, what does "do not stack" mean exactly here?

Comment: @AnatolyG with "do not stack" I meant: If a monitor is entered while already inside a monitor, will it cause some trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your explanation...

1. I know only one possible issue when "a monitor is entered while already inside a monitor". That's a deadlock when the first thread do something like this:

   ```
   synchronized  (object1) { // monitorenter for object1
       // code1
       synchronized (object2) { // monitorenter for object2
           //code2
       }
       //code3
   }
   ```

and the secod one:

```
    synchronized  (object2) { // monitorenter for object2
        // code2.1
        synchronized (object1) { // monitorenter for object1
           //code2.2
        }
       //code2.3
    }
```

When code1 is executing under lock on object1 and code2.1 is executing under lock on object2, we have a deadlock. The first thread will be waiting for object2 after object1 is finished and the second thread will be waiting for object1 infinitely. This is "a stack". There is a common rule for nested locking: use the same order of locking in all threads. Or just eliminate nested locks.

If you do monitorenter for one instance second time

```
    synchronized  (object1) { // monitorenter for object1
        // code1
        synchronized (object1) { // monitorenter for object1
            //code2
        }
        //code3
    }
```

JDK 7 with -XX:+EliminateNestedLocks ("on" by default), when monitor object is static final or when locking on this object, optimizes your code to:

```
    synchronized  (object1) { // monitorenter for object1
        //code1
        //code2
        //code3
    }
```

2. Anyway, if you see code2 executed (with no exceptions, of course), code3 must be started as well

Comment: Can you please also explain what happens when -XX:+EliminateNestedLocks is not turned on?

Comment: Then jvm does monitorenter/monitorenter twice. But the nested part is cheaper, since the current thread already has this monitor locked and should leave it locked after monitorenter (as in case when you call some synchronized code recurrently). There is no a functional difference between eliminated and non-eliminated nested locks. That optimization just improves performance slightly (a pair of nested monitorenter/monitorenter costs 100s nanoseconds)

Comment: Heh, there is a typo in my last comment) "locked after monitorexit", of course, instead of "locked after monitorenter"

Answer (score 1):

You may have heard that the feature of `synchronized` in the Java language does not map exactly to the `monitorenter`/`monitorexit` Java bytecode instructions. The exact details are:

`monitorenter` and `monitorexit` do “nest”, i.e. will increase a lock count on the particular object instance which will be free only when the counter will again reach zero. However, the JVM will, unlike the `synchronized` statement, not enforce a pairing of `monitorenter` and `monitorexit` instructions. Thus, the guaranty that after leaving a `synchronized` statement, regardless of normally or exceptionally, the lock will be released (or the internal counter decreased), must be enforced by the compiler by emitting code equivalent to the following pseudo code:

```
monitorenter(object);
try {
   // contents of the synchronized block
}
finally {
   monitorexit(object);
}
```

The JVM will accept byte code without such strong protection. The specification leaves it open to the JVM implementations to do a check for dangling `monitorenter`s on method exit. The last time I checked it, Oracle’s JVM did such tests and reset of the locking state on method exits. In case of a normal method exit with unpaired monitor operations it will generate an `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

To cite the [relevant part of the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.10):

> *Structured locking* is the situation when, during a method invocation, every exit on a given monitor matches a preceding entry on that monitor. Since there is no assurance that all code submitted to the Java Virtual Machine will perform structured locking, implementations of the Java Virtual Machine are permitted but not required to enforce both of the following two rules guaranteeing structured locking. Let *T* be a thread and *M* be a monitor. Then:
>
> 1. The number of monitor entries performed by *T* on *M* during a method invocation must equal the number of monitor exits performed by *T* on *M* during the method invocation whether the method invocation completes normally or abruptly.
> 2. At no point during a method invocation may the number of monitor exits performed by *T* on *M* since the method invocation exceed the number of monitor entries performed by *T* on *M* since the method invocation.